# Sudo permissions disaster

Tags: permissions, sudo

I just got a Pi-4. I'm not sure if I did something wrong while setting it up, but after getting it running I noticed that `sudo` commands required no passwords. I tried to change this, following some advice I found here:

[How to change user pi sudo permissions; how to add other accounts with different permissions?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-to-change-user-pi-sudo-permissions-how-to-add-other-accounts-with-different)

As that person recommended, I first added an admin user:

```
$ sudo adduser admin
```

Then I did the following:

```
$ sudo adduser admin sudo
$ sudo adduser admin adm
```

I then checked the user's privileges as advised, and it worked great. All good so far. Then I did the following as recommended:

```
$ sudo deluser pi sudo
$ sudo deluser pi adm
```

That worked great, too. Then I did something foolish. Unclear on precisely what I was supposed to do next, I opened up `010_pi-nopasswd` to edit it.  The file contained just one line:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I changed it -- and here is the foolish part, working faster than I was thinking -- to this:

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:
```

The Pi did NOT like this. Whether I am logged on as admin or pi I cannot use `sudo` for anything.(I did not create a root password before doing all this, so I can't use `su` either.) This means I also cannot go back and edit that file. Any attempt to do so triggers the following:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd: syntax error near line 1 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoer sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Likewise, any other use of `sudo` triggers the same. Is there any way around this problem or have I effectively ruined the OS?

Comment: `pkexec` might be installed and working, try using that instead of `sudo`.

Comment: next time you try that - create an interactive superuser session by using sudo -u ... it should last even when you "borked" the 010_pi-nopasswd

Comment: Most "click-bait-y" title. Ever. +1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong during setup.  By default, user "pi" can issue sudo commands with no password; that's the way Raspbian is released.  If you haven't done very much other customizing, just re-flash the microSD card and start over.

If you *really* need to rescue the contents of the current card, flash a new card and boot the Pi from it.  Put the current card into a USB adapter, plug it into a USB port, and you will be able to mount the partitions of the original card, edit files (with sudo) and fix your mistake.  (At least, I think so; I haven't actually tested this.)

If you have physical access to a running Linux system, you could use that rather than flashing a second SD card for the Pi.  Also note the comment and link from @goldilocks below about using a "live Linux" CD to *get* a running Linux system fairly easily.

To protect against breaking the sudo system, in the future use the `visudo` command when editing sudo's files.  It won't let you save a file with a syntax error.

For completeness, the following comes from the [visudo man page](https://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.7.10/visudo.man.html):

> `visudo` parses the sudoers file after the edit and will not save the changes if there is a syntax error. Upon finding an error, visudo will print a message stating the line number(s) where the error occurred and the user will receive the “What now?” prompt. At this point the user may enter ‘e’ to re-edit the sudoers file, ‘x’ to exit without saving the changes, or ‘Q’ to quit and save changes. The ‘Q’ option should be used with extreme care because if visudo believes there to be a parse error, so will sudo and no one will be able to sudo again until the error is fixed. If ‘e’ is typed to edit the sudoers file after a parse error has been detected, the cursor will be placed on the line where the error occurred (if the editor supports this feature).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your answer and will use visudo moving forward. I do have access to a Linux system.

Comment: It's easy to set the root password to nothing if you have privileged access to the filesystem (eg., by sticking the SD card in another machine, the system does not have to be running): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47129/5538  ...By "nothing" I mean that you will be able to log in as root without any password when the system is running.

Comment: The suggestion in the link above to use a Linux "live CD" is an extremely good one for someone who doesn't have an extra SD card handy. Download a file, burn a CD, and you're set!

Comment: fellow viphobes please note that you don't _have_ to use the worst text editor still in common usage today, even though the command starts with the feared "vi": ```sudo SUDO_EDITOR=emacs visudo``` or ```sudo SUDO_EDITOR=joe visudo``` will preserve your sanity! Make an alias and never have to type "vi" until the next time you're setting up a new installation and you FORCIBLY DELETE IT FROM YOUR SYSTEM (like I do) :-D

Comment: @AaronF yeah, right? I always never get the grips with these weird text editors. Unfortunately your advice didn't work, I tried to set MS Paint as my text editor but wasn't able to use it for editing sudoers.d files.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you just didn't have Wine installed... oh, and QEMU...

Answer (score 3):

The Answer by Bob Brown is correct but if all you want to do is remove password less sudo just delete the `010_pi-nopasswd` file.

This can be done on a Linux computer.

You could also log in to a root shell on the Pi to delete the file.
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/79202/8697

Comment: Thanks. I do have access to a Linux computer. Is it easy to log into the root shell on the Pi and delete the 010-pi file if I never set a password for root on the Pi (though I did set a password for the "pi" user)? I have never done this before.

Comment: If yo have a root shell you can simply revert the edit...

Comment: I just want to say thanks to Bob Brown and to goldilocks and Peter and to everyone else who weighed in. This was great advice. I popped the SD card into a linux machine, as advised, and was able to delete the {010_pi-nopasswd} file. Pi is no longer a sudo user, only my admin user is, and password is required, which is what I was trying to do from the start.  The machine is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Never change manually the sudoers file !!!

In case you did it wrong (as i did T_T), a working solution can be found here :
https://sites.google.com/site/nandydandyoracle/tools/pkexec-visudo-no-session-for-cookie

Good luck !!

Comment: Hello! And welcome :-). Your answer should contain the information needed to solve the problem, and not only link to another page. You can keep the link, but you should explain here what it says. Such that later, if the link dies, the answer is still valid :-)