# Restart lxpanel through shell script; works in shell, but not in cron

Tags: raspbian, cron

I have a raspberry pi which stays on for extended period of time. To avoid it from crashing, I have a cron job that periodically checks for top memory consuming apps and then restarts them as needed. The shell script monitors the services correctly but for some reason doesn't restart lxpanel correctly. The shell script runs as sudo and uses the following to restart the lxpanel service:

`sudo -u mimo lxpanelctl restart`
, where mimo is my username

I do not see a drop in memory usage, so it doesn't seem that the command successfully restarts lxpanel. Whereas if I run `lxpanelctl restart` from a terminal instance, I do see the required/expected drop in lxpanel's memory usage.

So now the question is how can I run lxpanelctl restart from within the script.

I've tried:

- `lxpanelctl restart`, which when invoked from the script running as sudo, kills the desktop session and requires a relogin
- `sudo -u mimo lxpanelctl restart` doesn't appear to actually restart the panel as I do not see a drop in mem usage.
- `runuser -l mimo -c 'lxpanelctl restart'` doesn't appear to actually restart the panel as I do not see a drop in mem usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` does not run in the same [*environment*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm) as the shell in your terminal.

> Think about this for a moment before moving on... let it sink in.

Let's do an experiment:

At the shell prompt (I'll assume `bash`) in your terminal, check what your *environment* is using the following command:

```bsh
$ printenv
```

Note particularly, in the output of this command, the value of the *environment variable* `PATH`; for example, on my system it is:

`PATH=/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

You may be tempted to **assume** that your `cron` job runs under the same *environment*... after all, it is ***your*** `crontab`. But let's try to confirm that assumption by asking `cron` to tell us what its *environment* actually is.

To do this, we'll create another `cron` job for that purpose: Open your `crontab` for editing (`crontab -e` - or - `sudo crontab -e` if you need elevated privileges for your job), and add the following line:

```
* * * * * printenv > /home/pi/cronenvironment.txt 2>&1
```

Once this has run, inspect the file `/home/pi/cronenvironment.txt`, and again, pay particular attention to the `PATH` environment variable. For example on my system:

`PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`

And so we see that the `PATH` environment variable under `cron` is not the same as the `PATH` in your `bash` shell.

This suggests a *potential* cause for your problem:

> `lxpanelctl` is not in a directory that is in `cron's` `PATH`.

If that's the case, the best remedy is also the simplest:

```
sudo -u mimo /full/path/to/lxpanelctl restart
```

Let us know how this works, or if you have any questions.

---

Just as a comment: If you need elevated privileges in a `cron` job, it is often a better solution to use the `root crontab` *instead of* using `sudo` in your `user pi crontab`; i.e. use `sudo crontab -e`. You can get away with using `sudo` inside a user `crontab` in RPi OS only because this distro is [default-configured with the `NOPASSWD` declaration for user `pi`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108206/sudo-permissions-disaster). That's not typical, and is "frowned upon" by some who spend time thinking about computer security. And finally, do not invoke `sudo` in the `root crontab`.

P.S. You should now disable the `cron` job you added to run `printenv`.

Comment: Yeah running the script as sudo cron.

The full path `/full/path/to/lxpanelctl restart` did help but now I am getting "cant connect to display: (null)" error, which I do not get running the command directly in the terminal

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was able to fix: "cant connect to display: (null)" by exporting DISPLAY=":0.0". All working as intended after that

Comment: @Akt: Yes - `DISPLAY` being another environment variable. Glad this helped, and [please read this.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)